# Copy last 300 rows to another column

Tags: excel

I have thousand rows (keep updated) in one column A.
What is the formula to show last 300 rows in column B
Thank you

Comment: Define "show"? How would you want it to be show? Simply displaying the last 300 rows of records from column A in column B?

Comment: Sorry if my question confusing. Simple comand:
In column B, copy the last 300 rows from column A which is contain text or value.
Thanks

Comment: A formula is a pretty bad way to go about this particular problem. You'll probably want VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If we did this manually and there were exactly 300 rows in column **A** we would:

1. find the last row *(300)*
2. subtract 299 from that *(to get the first row)*
3. copy the block from 1 thru 300 to column **B**

In **C1** enter:

```
=MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,A:A)
```

This tells use where the data ends.

In **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,$C$1-299+ROW()-1)
```

and copy down this formula down from **B2** through **B300.**.

Comment: @RajaParhata The formula in **C1** should give the row number of the last filled cell in column **A** The cells **B1** through **B300** will contain the actual values,

Comment: since column A will  be updated any time. Sothe check point is will be the last value in column A..then retrive back..

Comment: The value in cell **C1** will automatically adjust as data is added or removed from column **A**

Comment: Finally is works, either i make a mistake or there's some difference version of excel that i use..thank you for your help..